# problem storing high score for a number guessing game in java

Tags: java, loops, variables, while-loop, nested-loops

I'm having problems storing the high score of the game with multiple players who each have a different name and score. no matter the players score, the code outputs that they beat the high score. the maximum number of rounds is 15. the problem seems to be the high score variable resets when going through the full loop again and doesn't keep the previous high score  for a new player. the entire game function is inside a do while loop.

```
String highScorer = " ";
                int highScore = 15;
                if (score < highScore) {
                    highScorer = name;
                    highScore = score;
                    System.out.println("Congrats! You beat the high score!");
                }
                //output person with high score
                System.out.println("The high score belongs to " + highScorer + " at " + highScore + " tries!");
```

The code doesn't store the high score consistently when looping through the do while loop for multiple players

Comment: With that few code, it will be impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1):

> high score variable resets when going through the full loop again

From the above line, you might have initialized the `highScore` variable inside the loop. Try to initialize outside the loop so that it won't be reset.